# How to pass messages in codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter, session

How to pass `error messages` and `success messages` to one function to another using `Codeigniter`?
I need to show messages in my view when that action success or fail.

Comment: what did you tried?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

two ways to do it.

01) You can use `flashdata`

its very simple.

```
$this->session->set_flashdata('give_some_useful_word', 'value');
```

set your message variable to `value`.

now you can use it any where in controller like this,

```
$this->session->flashdata('given_word');
```

02)You can use `sessions`

```
$this->session->set_userdata('give_some_useful_word', 'value');
```

add your message varible to `value`.

now you can use it any where in controller like this,

```
$this->session->userdata('given_word');
```

Both are like same coding but I recomanded 1st method.

further knowldge [here](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/sessions.html)

Comment: Best is to use method one as it is automatically cleared on the next request. With `set_userdata()` the message will keep existing until you clear session data. (Also, they are both part of the session library. So method 2 is actually "You can use `userdata`".)